# Python embedding, ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref

Tags: python, c++, macos

I am trying to run some C++ code with embedded Python. Code was working completely fine a couple of weeks ago. The code still compiles, but I am now getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .main import TestProgram, main
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import loader, runner
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/runner.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .signals import registerResult
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/signals.py", line 2, in <module>
    import weakref
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

Since then the only change I have made is to install the macOS Supplemental Update and to upgrade Python from 2.7.13_1 to 2.7.14_2 (using Homebrew). I have changed the relevant linker flags in the makefile, i.e. those that appear when I type `python-config --ldflags`. I have also made sure that the Python I am using is definitely the Homebrew one by inserting `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"` into my .bash_profile as directed by Homebrew.

I am not sure whether this error is because of the Python update, the recent macOS Supplemental Update, or something else. Any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks

Comment: This problem is definitely something to do with importing numpy, as suggested by the error message. I've tried embedding Python modules without `import numpy` and that works fine. If I import numpy in a python interpreter in the terminal, that also works.

Comment: I have the same problem. The import works fine from interpreter shell script but when using embedded code PyImport_Import(pName); fails with the same error. Did anyone find the solution?

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/918298/266914) suggests that the issue is possibly related to upgrading Python and how it impacts existing virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem;
In python 2.7 the NumPy 1.8.0 was available,
Then I installed NumPy (again) using brew, and it wasn't available in my python (2.7) anymore. (Got the same error you got here)

So I did "brew unlink python && brew link python" to use python 3 (instead of 2) which NumPy 1.14 is available in it.
I guess the python 2.7 was not compatible with this recent version of NumPy.